# which shell-command in emacs lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

If I am trying to run a shell-command in an Emacs Lisp function in which I call `rsync` (or `scp`) multiple times, which shell-command variant should I use? I am currently using `shell-command`, which locks up Emacs until the process is done, and the output that should be visible with the `--verbose` to `rsync` is not printed; I can use `shell-command` with an `&` at the end of the command string to make it asynchronous, which does print the progress — but while it doesn't "lock up" Emacs entirely, the minibuffer repeatedly asks if I want to kill the process which is crippling in the meantime; and `start-process-shell-command`, which appears to halt the function only after the first file/directory is transferred; neglecting the rest when there are multiple `rsync` calls made through my function. None of these seem ideal, any hints?

Comment: Have you read http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have had the most success using start-process myself.

```
(start-process "process-name" 
               (get-buffer-create "*rsync-buffer*") 
               "/path/to/rsync"
               arg1
               ...
               argn)
```

This will send all the output to a single buffer.

Answer (score 5):

One solution might be to run the command in an actual [shell buffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryShell).  Then you get to choose which one of those to run:

```
M-x shell
M-x eshell
M-x term
```

If you like that idea, you can code it up like this:

```
(defun my-rsync-routine ()
  "run some rsync processes"
  (with-temp-buffer
    (shell (current-buffer))
    (process-send-string nil "rsync ...")
    (process-send-string nil "rsync ...")
    (process-send-string nil "rsync ...")))
```

Read more on [`'process-send-string`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-to-Processes.html) for its usage.  You might also want to have some error checking on the [output](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-from-Processes.html#Output-from-Processes) from the processes.

Comment: Hello Trey, thank you always. This time I had to choose with Jonathan's solution but as it was direct and well-suited for this purpose (and process-send-string seemed to work only in a buffer created and explicitly referenced (with get-buffer-create) rather than in temp-buffer...) but I am reading up on the filtering functions... there is much to grok and I am sure I will find uses at the end of it. Thank you again.